# What is Namecoin's blocksize limit?

Tags: namecoin, blocksize

Bitcoin's blocksize limit is currently 1MB. It seems as if Namecoin would have to be bigger due to it proving 512 bytes of storage with a name update, but it also has slower average block times (about 20 minutes according to [BitInfoCharts](https://bitinfocharts.com/namecoin/)).

Does Namecoin also have block size limit? What size is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namecoin has not strayed from Bitcoin in this parameter, it is still set at a 1 MB block size limit. You can find it in [main.h](https://github.com/namecoin/namecoin/blob/namecoinq/src/main.h#L42-L43):

```
/** The maximum allowed size for a serialized block, in bytes (network rule) */
static const unsigned int MAX_BLOCK_SIZE = 1000000;
```